# Monitor IP Addresses accessing my VM in Azure

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine, monitor

Is there a way to monitor IP address that access my Virtual Machine hosted in Azure?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "access my Virtual Machine"? Do you mean from which IP address a user connected to your VM via RDP or something else?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. There is an administration account provided to multiple people. I would like to know who and when has been connected with this administration account to this VM by their IP addresses. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in this thread

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/efabde54-be5e-4be2-bf1b-b146934047e1/logging-ip-adderess-during-remote-desktop-connection?forum=winserverTS

All the logs are stored in here: Event Viewer\Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager

Hope this thread would help others!